# class extending another class with parameters only known during run-time

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a class `ExtendedTableView` by extending `TableView`, I want to allow users to create an extendedTableView with settings pre-set and allow cells to be editable. The following is a code section showing briefly how the cell is edited:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));
        //Create a customer cell factory so that cells can support editing.
        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                return new EditingCell();
            }
        };

        //Set up the columns
        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth( 100 );
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth( 100 );
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
//        lastNameCol.setEditable( false );
        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(400);
        TableColumn primaryEmailCol = new TableColumn("Primary Email");
        primaryEmailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        primaryEmailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("primaryEmail"));
        primaryEmailCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        //Make this column un-editable        
        primaryEmailCol.setEditable( false );
        TableColumn secondaryEmailCol = new TableColumn("Secondary Email");
        secondaryEmailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        secondaryEmailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("secondaryEmail"));
        secondaryEmailCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
//        secondaryEmailCol.setEditable( false );
        emailCol.getColumns().addAll(primaryEmailCol, secondaryEmailCol);
        //Add the columns and data to the table.
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);
        //Make the table editable
        table.setEditable(true);
        //Modifying the firstName property
        firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });
        //Modifying the lastName property
        lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setLastName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });
        //Modifying the primary email property
        primaryEmailCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setPrimaryEmail(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });
        //Modifying the secondary email property
        secondaryEmailCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setSecondaryEmail(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });
        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
}

public class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {
    private TextField textField;
    public EditingCell() {
    }
    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField();
        }
        setGraphic(textField);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textField.requestFocus();
                textField.selectAll();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText((String) getItem());
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setGraphic(textField);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
            }
        }
    }
    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    TableColumn nextColumn = getNextColumn(!t.isShiftDown());
                    if (nextColumn != null) {
                        getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(), nextColumn);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                if (!newValue && textField != null) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param forward true gets the column to the right, false the column to the left of the current column
     * @return
     */
    private TableColumn<Person, ?> getNextColumn(boolean forward) {
        List<TableColumn<Person, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        for (TableColumn<Person, ?> column : getTableView().getColumns()) {
            columns.addAll(getLeaves(column));
        }
        //There is no other column that supports editing.
        if (columns.size() < 2) {
            return null;
        }
        int currentIndex = columns.indexOf(getTableColumn());
        int nextIndex = currentIndex;
        if (forward) {
            nextIndex++;
            if (nextIndex > columns.size() - 1) {
                nextIndex = 0;
            }
        } else {
            nextIndex--;
            if (nextIndex < 0) {
                nextIndex = columns.size() - 1;
            }
        }
        return columns.get(nextIndex);
    }

    private List<TableColumn<Person, ?>> getLeaves(TableColumn<Person, ?> root) {
        List<TableColumn<Person, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        if (root.getColumns().isEmpty()) {
            //We only want the leaves that are editable.
            if (root.isEditable()) {
                columns.add(root);
            }
            return columns;
        } else {
            for (TableColumn<Person, ?> column : root.getColumns()) {
                columns.addAll(getLeaves(column));
            }
            return columns;
        }
    }
}
```

The above example shows that the class `EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String>`, but what I am trying to do is something like this:

```
public class ExtendedTableView extends TableView{
  public ExtendedTableView(){
    init();
  }
  private void init(){
    this.setEditable(true);
    this.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);
  }
}

public class EditingCell extends TableCell<UNKNOWN, String>{

    private TableColumn<UNKNOWN, ?> getNextColumn(boolean forward) {
    }

}
```

I want users to be able to do something like `ExtendedTableView table = new ExtendedTableView()` to get a table that has all settings pre-set and with the cells editable. It doesn't matter if I have to add a few more lines such as passing in the class/classtype(instead of `Person` class). But the idea is to create a customized tableview so that its generic enough and the users doesn't need to know the codes required to make the cells editable etc.

```
public class MyClass{
  public MyClass(){
  }

  public void createTable(){
    ExtendedTableView tableA = new ExtendedTableView();
    ExtendedTableView tableB = new ExtendedTableView();
    /*somehow find a way to pass classA into tableA so that class table cell can be something like this: "TableCell < ClassA, String>"*/
  }
}

public class classA{
}

public class classB{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, if you are using raw types any time after 2010, you are probably not doing things the best way. (Specifically, don't use raw types unless you are interacting with legacy - meaning pre-Java 1.5 - code.)

In this case, you just need to make your `ExtendedTableView` class generic, i.e. give it a type parameter:

```
public class ExtendedTableView<T> extends TableView<T> {

    public ExtendedTableView(){
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        this.setEditable(true);
        this.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and similarly for your `EditingCell` class:

```
public class EditingCell<T> extends TableCell<T, String>{

    private TableColumn<T, ?> getNextColumn(boolean forward) {
    }

}
```

Now, given

```
public class ClassA { /* ... */ }
```

and

```
public class ClassB { /* ... */ }
```

your client code can just do

```
ExtendedTableView<ClassA> tableA = new ExtendedTableView<>();
ExtendedTableView<ClassB> tableB = new ExtendedTableView<>();
```

and you can do things like

```
TableColumn<ClassA, String> someColumn = new TableColumn<>();
tableA.getColumns().add(someColumn);
someColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new EditingCell<>());
```

Comment: Yes yes Yes!! Oh god.. I have been struggling to find a way to explain what I want, I knew it's something simple but I'm not sure how to approach it.. Thank you so much! This is exactly what i wanted!